# Implementation of interfaces and components in a component-based framework

Tags: java, android, interface, frameworks, components

I'm currently trying to develop a small component-based android framework, but I have a doubt about which is the best way to implement my components and interfaces. An architecture of one of my components is shown below.

[image: My Model]

My doubt is, should I create one implementation per interface ( *i.e* ClientBuyHistoryImpl, CallClientImpl, etc. ) and create a **ClientsSystem** class that would be my component and then declare those implemented interfaces inside it. **e.g. :**

```
public class ClientsSystem {

    public IClientBuyHistory clientBuyHistoryImpl;
    public ICallClient callClientImpl;

    /* ... */
}
```

Or should I create a class that implements all interfaces? **e.g. :**

```
public class ClientSystem implements IClientBuyHistory, ICallClient{

    @Override
    /* ... */

    @Override
    /* ... */
}
```

Another approach I was thinking about is to use [Dagger2](http://google.github.io/dagger/) to create Modules and Components and then inject them, but this way, How would be the implementation? My interface's implementation will become a **Module** and my component class would become a **Component**.?

Comment: I would probably be more in favor of making an implementation per interface, and then using them to compose whatever the system requires through a factory. How the ClientSystem class is supposed to be used ? Is it supposed to be a facade or something ?

Comment: What don't you try to inject the required component implementation inside ClientSystem methods ? You could used inversion of control, that would be probably a better approach. I can provide you an example, if you wish.